# AS3 - Detecting if you clicked on an object without pressing the mouse button

Tags: actionscript-3, object, click, point, hittest

Okay, in as3 when you click, the object on the highest layer will be clicked on. I want someone to press the space bar and have the objects on the screen to check to see if it is touching a point.

So I first tried hittest...

if (this.hitTest(myPoint)){
      play();
  }

Now the problem was objects behind other ones were thinking they were being "clicked" on.

Then after being frustrated I used Google, couldn't find anything so please anything helps.

Comment: Would it help to disable mouse events on those objects that aren't relevant?  `mouseEnabled=false` and possibly `mouseChildren=false`

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the code you are looking for:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, function(e : KeyboardEvent) : void {
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
        var objects : Array = stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY));
        if (objects.length > 0) {
            var topmost : DisplayObject = objects[objects.length-1];
            trace(topmost.name);
        }
    }
});
```

Key is flash's [getObjectsUnderPoint](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_de/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getObjectsUnderPoint%28%29) method.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> DisplayObjectContainer.getObjectsUnderPoint()
> ```

Be mindful `getObjectsUnderPoint` doesn't return DisplayObjectContainers, as evidenced here:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var shape:Shape = new Shape();
    shape.graphics.beginFill(0);
    shape.graphics.drawRect(0,0,5,5);
mc.addChild(shape);
var shape2:Shape = new Shape();
    shape2.graphics.beginFill(0);
    shape2.graphics.drawRect(0,0,5,5);
mc.addChild(shape2);
addChild(mc);
getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(1,1)); // returns [object Shape],[object Shape]
```

You can use the `parent` property of returned DisplayObjects to find a DisplayObjectContainer...

```
var containerBeingLocated:Sprite;

for each (var obj:DisplayObject in objectsUnderPoint) {
    if (isWithin(obj, containerBeingLocated)) {
        trace('container located');
    }
}

function isWithin ($obj:DisplayObject, $container:DisplayObjectContainer):Boolean {
    while ($obj) {
        if ($obj === $container) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $obj = $obj.parent;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an excellent question that I don't have a ready-coded solution for. Exactly which thing is in the foreground getting clicked on is one of those things you take for granted when you get it for free as a MouseEvent target. The easy part is setting up all your display objects to listen for the KeyboardEvent corresponding to pressing the spacebar, and to hit test with the mouse position at that time.

The rest of your problem, the real problem, seems to me to boil down to one determination you need to make: A and B occupy the same screen space, which one is in front. In other words, once you have a list of all the DisplayObjects for which the hitTest is a hit, you need this compare function to sort them front to back. Here is how I see that working:

To determine if DisplayObject A is in front of or behind DisplayObject B, you need to trace their display list ancestry back to their common ancestor, and then look at the next generation down from that, to see if--at the point where their ancestry diverges--object A's ancestor is in front of or behind object B's (i.e. their relative depths in the common ancestor container). Consider a display tree like this:

```
       E
      / \
     C   D
    /     \
   A       B
```

E is the common ancestor. To determine if A is behind B, you need to check if C is behind D, which means you need to check C and D's depths in the E container (with DisplayObjectContainer.getChildIndex(child)). Obviously, in a complex UI the common ancestor could be many generations back, but there will always be one even if it's the stage.

**EDIT:**

How did I overlook the obvious?! you don't want to click the mouse button, but didn't say you couldn't use MouseEvents at all, right? Use the ROLL_OVER or MOUSE_OVER event to keep track of what you've rolled over and hitTest with that object [slaps forehead in shame].

Comment: I thought this as well - but I wasn't sure if the question was suggesting that the Point would always be at the mouse position or not.

Comment: Indeed, it is not clear to me if the "point" in question is the mouse location, or an arbitrary point. Obviously the rollover approach only works if we're talking about what's under the mouse and just using the space bar as if it were the mouse button.

Comment: Yeah. Nice thought though. +1

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.. I'll have a look around, but for now all I can think of is having an array that contains all your objects (added in the same order as they were to the DisplayList) and then iterating through backwards to find the first collision.

Eg (and sorry for the very lazy example):

```
    var objs:Array = [];

/**
 * Returns an object at a point with the highest depth
 * @param at A Point to check at
 */
function checkForHighest(at:Point):DisplayObject
{
    var i:uint = objs.length-1;
    for(i; i>0; i--)
    {
        var j:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(objs[i]);

        if(objs.hitTest(at)) return objs[i];
    }

    return null;
}
```

The first DisplayObject found will be the highest in the DisplayList.